# Mathematical model for malaria

Tags: theoretical-biology, epidemiology, malaria

The simplest malaria model is as follows:
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{\alpha \beta I}{\alpha I + r} (1-I) - \mu I$$

where $r$ is the natural death rate of mosquitoes, $\mu$ is the death rate of humans, $\beta$ is the transmission rate from infected mosquitoes to susceptible humans, and $\alpha$ is the transmission rate from humans to mosquitoes. However, for $I \ge 1$, $dI/dt$ is negative. Wouldn't that imply that the infected class is always shrinking from the start? How does this make sense?

Comment: What is I? Overall infections?

Comment: Yes, $dI/dt$ is the rate of change of the infected population.

Comment: Where did the model come from? I'm thinking hard trying to figure this out, maybe a bit more background could help.

Comment: Martcheva, Introduction to Mathematical Epidemiology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you may have to read your textbook more closely. The question on page 29 states that this equation models **the proportion** of infected humans. If $I$  $≥1$ that would mean that there are more people are infected than there are people in total - e.g. 3/2 of people are infected - this clearly doesn't make sense.

Thus $1≥I$ when using this model.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for clarifying. You've spared me much frustration!